# How can I check that if img src start with http://img.youtube.com/vi/ and after any character and replace with a youtube video iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, iframe, youtube

So basically I would like to make a little lazy load code to my site.

Every Youtube video has a thumbnail and usually the url is something like this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<THEVIDEOID>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

I would like to detect this and if it's true, this can be a click event, and after you clicked the image, you get the iframe and you can play the video.

Now, I know there is thousand and thousand outsiders plugin in the internet, but I don't want to load any other code, just that function what is really necessary for this script to work (I hate big load times like anyone else).

Sometimes the outside plugins has thousand, and thousand unnecessary functions for me, like check on every load I chose the click method or the scroll method, and other not useful things.

That's why I decided I trying to build my own.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871489/replace-an-image-with-a-youtube-video) in the search results, but I would like to build this on jQuery way.

**Note:**

This need for a Wordpress site, that's why I use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

This  what I have now:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      function youtubecheck(){
        var myregexp = /[a-z,A-Z,0-9]/g;//Regexp for videoid
        var imageurl="http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+myregexp+"/maxresdefault.jpg";    // This doesn't sounds right, I need to find out something else.
        if (jQuery("img").attr("src")=== "imageurl"){
           var autoplay="?autoplay=1/"//this for iframe
           jQuery(this).addClass("YT-image");    // Obviously we need class, because we don't whant to do this with all images, just with YT-imgaes.
          jQuery(".YT-image").click(function() {
            jQuery(".YT-image").replaceWith('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+myregexp+autoplay+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');    // maybe we need each for every image? Also I'm not sure about "myregexp" variable in here.
      });
    }
  }
  youtubecheck();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url

Comment: @Andreas I think this can't be work becouse on the answer the keything is this:
"`window.location.search.split('v=')[1];`" but we have a close tag in the end like `/vi/` but not was bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your if condition and regex

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function youtubecheck() {
    if (/img\.youtube\.com\/vi\/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]+\/maxresdefault\.jpg/g.test(jQuery("img").attr("src"))) {
      var videoId = /img\.youtube\.com\/vi\/(.*?)\/maxresdefault\.jpg/g.exec(jQuery("img").attr("src"))[1];
      var autoplay = "?autoplay=1/"; //this for iframe
      jQuery("img").addClass("YT-image"); //Obviously we need class, becouse we don't whant to do this with all images, just with YT-imgaes.
      jQuery(".YT-image").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + autoplay + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'); // maybe we need each for every image? Also I'm not sure about "myregexp" varible in here.
      });
    }
  }
  youtubecheck();
});
```

Updated the code this works

Comment: Still dosen't work.
Please copy your url from url bar, do not copy my url.

Comment: @user3545446 did it work for you ?? if worked mark it as answer

Comment: Yeah, you overflow me, Now I only need to do one thing:
Solve that case when you click a image do not load all video on the post, just that one what is clicked

Comment: I made mistake with autoplay atribute becose it's not `?autoplay=1/` but `?autoplay=1` good to know :D